# PluginManagment of versions without parent pom

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am looking for a way to have spring boot manage some plugin verisons without using the spring boot pom as my parent pom.  Basically I do not want a parent pom (long story but I don't want one).  However I still want version management of decencies and plugins.  I found the below solution from spring documentation to manage dependency versions, but I cannot find how to manage plugin verisons.  Is there something similar to the below logic to manage the verisons of my plugins?

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Below is an example of what I am looking to have managed.  In previous projects my parent pom would take care of versions of some of my plugins.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>some group<groupId>
    <artifactId>some artifact</artifactId>
    <version>I want this managed without a parent pom</version>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to manage that yourself. As documented the parent handles items like `pluginManagement` which you do not get with using the BOM. For the Spring Maven Plugin you could tie that to whatever version of the BOM you are using as they are versioned the same.

> If you do not want to use the spring-boot-starter-parent, you can still keep the benefit of the dependency management (but not the plugin management) by using a scope=import dependency, as follows:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

Additionally there is nothing like a BOM for plugin's, from the maven docs

> This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Edit,

I did find this https://release-engineering.github.io/pom-manipulation-ext/guide/plugin-manip.html

Which may be of use depending on how complex your POM etc. are and why you don't want to inherit from Spring's parent.